# Are local robots.txt files read by Facebook and Google?

Tags: facebook, seo, robots.txt

I have a folder which is half public: The URL is not linked, the people that know the URL are only a few friends (which will not link it) and it is cryptic enough to make sure that nobody lands there by accident.

However, the link is send via Googlemail and Facebook messages. Is there a way to tell Facebook and Google in a local robots.txt file not to index the page?

When I add it to the "global" robots.txt file then everybody who takes a look there will see that in my `/secret-folder-12argoe22v4` might be something interesting. So I will not do that. But will Facebook / Google look at `/secret-folder-12argoe22v4/robots.txt`?

The content would be

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: .
```

or

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /secret-folder-12argoe22v4/
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a “local robots.txt” – by its very _definition_ a robots.txt is located at root level. // You could try and use a robots meta tag instead to disallow indexing.

Comment: Asking how search engines will display/rank/parse your site is off topic. It might be more suitable on [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), but check their scope and existing questions.

Answer (score 1):

As CBroe mentioned, a robots.txt file must always be at the top level of the site. If you put it in a subdirecory, it will be ignored. One way you **can** block a directory without publicly revealing its full name is to block just part of it, like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /secret
```

This will block any URL that starts with "/secret", including "/secret-folder-12argoe22v4/".

I should point out that the above is not a 100% reliable way to keep the files out of the search engines. It will keep the search engines from directly crawling the directory, but they can still show it in search results if some other site links to it. You may consider using robots meta tags instead, but even this won't prevent someone from directly following an off-site link. The only really reliable way to keep a directory private is to put it behind a password.